# (matlab) qtdecomp works with uint8 matrix?

Tags: matlab

I haven't fully understood how `qtdecomp` works...

```
I = [1    1    1    1    2    3    6    6
     1    1    2    1    4    5    6    8
     1    1    1    1   10   15    7    7
     1    1    1    1   20   25    7    7
    20   22   20   22    1    2    3    4
    20   22   22   20    5    6    7    8
    20   22   20   20    9   10   11   12
    22   22   20   20   13   14   15   16];

S = qtdecomp(I,2);
disp(full(S));
```

The results of this are:

```
   4     0     0     0     1     1     2     0
   0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
   0     0     0     0     1     1     2     0
   0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
   4     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
   0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
   0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
   0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
```

in the left bottom 4*4 matrix, maximum value (22) of the block elements minus the minimum value (20) is 2, so when decomposing this part, it will left as is.

When I do this on a `uint8` matrix:

```
I = uint8([...
     1    1    1    1    2    3    6    6
     1    1    2    1    4    5    6    8
     1    1    1    1   10   15    7    7
     1    1    1    1   20   25    7    7
    20   22   20   22    1    2    3    4
    20   22   22   20    5    6    7    8
    20   22   20   20    9   10   11   12
    22   22   20   20   13   14   15   16]);

S = qtdecomp(I,2/255);
disp(full(S));
```

the answer is just like before. But when I change `S` to this:

```
S = qtdecomp(I,1.9/255);
```

The answer is

```
 4     0     0     0     1     1     2     0
 0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     1     2     0
 0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
 4     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
```

I suppose the left bottom 4*4 matrix should decompose, but why doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What matlab does here is when `I` is uint8 it multiples the threshold by 255 and rounds it, so 1.9/255 is evaluated to 2.

You can see this by opening the source code for `qtdecomp` (by pressing ctrl+D) or [here](http://www4.hcmut.edu.vn/~huynhqlinh/TinhocDC/WebLQNguyen/matlab/tai%20lieu/MATLAB6_COURSE/WORK/IMAGES/IMAGES/QTDECOMP.M). There's an if/elseif near the end of the file (`params{1} = round(255 * params{1});`).

You should be able to use `S = qtdecomp(I,1/255);` to get the result you are looking for.